# Fastify Response Validation not working as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, fastify, ajv

I have recently upgraded fastify to v4, I am using its plugin @fastify-response-validation (latest version), recently I observed that keywords like "minLength", "maxLength", "enum", "format" are not taking effect and incorrect responses are getting through.

While certain keywords like "required" are working as expected. I am not able to debug till now what has gone wrong in the process.

I am not using ajv-formats and ajv-errors as separate plugins. I believe these basic validations should work without these.

Please help.

```
const server = fastify({
    ajv: {
      customOptions: {
        allErrors: true,
        coerceTypes: "array",
        useDefaults: true,
        allowUnionTypes: true,
        formats,
      },
    },
    logger: true,
    trustProxy: true,
    exposeHeadRoutes: false,
  });

server.register(fastifyResponseValidation, {
    ajv: {
      strict: true,
      schemas,
      coerceTypes: false,
    },
  });
```

Comment: Later I figured that actually @fastify-response-validation's registration had turned asynchronous and I was missing that little "await", the basic coercion were still working and I was under the impression that its working partially as coercion validation happens during serialization. I hope this would help someone.

Answer (score 1):

fastify-response-validation is deprecated.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/fastify-response-validation

> fastify-response-validation@0.3.0 has been deprecated. Please use @fastify/response-validation@1.0.0 instead.

Can you try @fastify/response-validation?